# JavaScript code for adding days to a text field based on other text field in oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

JavaScript code  to add  60 days automatically to  release_date field when enter an date to resignation_date field in Oracle Apex .

Comment: Is it mendatory to use JS? This is easily achievable with a dynamic action executing PLSQL to set the value of release date. :RELEASE_DATE := :REGISTRATION_DATE + 60;

Comment: JavaScript does automatically as soon as we enter resignation_date at client side that is why

Comment: so can you create an additional dynamic action executing PLSQL code triggered on change of field registration_date?

Comment: Its working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Damir's suggestion to use a Dynamic Action with PL/SQL is a good one. But if you want a true client-side solution, look into https://date-fns.org/. See the `addDays` function: https://date-fns.org/v2.8.0/docs/addDays

Comment: Thanks Dan Mcghan